# Use array as data values in Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, highcharts

I am using a highcharts.js library to generate a profit & loss chart for my website
I have an array whose values I get from an ajax response from my server.

**This is that code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var profit = [];
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "/php/get-inflow.php",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data){
            for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
                if(data[i] == null){
                    profit[i] = 0;  
            }else{
                    profit[i] = data[i];
                }   
            }
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('#profitloss').highcharts({
//some other highcharts code
series: [{
                name: 'Inflow',
                data: profit
            }, {
                name: 'Outflow',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I think the array (profit[]) is not recognized or this is not a valid way? thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Because ajax call is asynchronous, `profit` array is still empty (defined as []) when chart is displayed. You have to move code for chart creation to ajax `success()` function like:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $.ajax({
      url : "/php/get-inflow.php",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data){
            for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
                if(data[i] == null){
                    profit[i] = 0;  
            }else{
                    profit[i] = data[i];
                }   
            }

            $('#profitloss').highcharts({
                //some other highcharts code
                series: [{
                    name: 'Inflow',
                    data: profit
                }, {
                    name: 'Outflow',
                    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
                }]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Another option is to make function which draw a chart:

```
function drawChart() {
    $('#profitloss').highcharts({
        series: [{
            name: 'Inflow',
            data: profit
        }, {
            name: 'Outflow',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
        }]
    });
}
```

and call that function after `for` loop in `success()` function:

```
  success: function(data){
        for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] == null){
                profit[i] = 0;  
            }else{
                profit[i] = data[i];
            }
        }
        drawChart();
    }
```